# html load picture using web address

Tags: php, html

I'm getting the web address of pictures on the internet from my database and displaying them back on the page, it is currently displaying the actual web address and not loading the actual picture, is it possible to get the actual picture to be loaded? (on the database the web address of the image is stored as a string)

```
           <tr>
            <!--<th>id</th>
               <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td> -->
              <th>Name</th>

               <td><?php echo $row['hname']; ?></td>
                       <th>image</th>

               <td><?php echo $row['himage']; ?></td>
                       <th>Description</th>

               <td><?php echo $row['hdesc']; ?></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Use the `<img>` element. Ex `<img src="<?php echo $row['himage']; ?>">`

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called an `img` tag.  Something like this:

```
<td><img src="<?php echo $row['himage']; ?>" /></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your image is stored for example in the root in the folder itages, then

```
<td><img src="/images/<?php echo $row['himage'];?>" /></td>
```

OR

```
<td><img src="/images/<?=$row['himage'];?>" /></td>
```